# Thoughts on graduate school application consultant?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, engineering, consulting

I plan to apply to graduate programs to get a master's degree. My undergraduate GPA isn't impressive (3.067, can I round that to 3.1 on my résumé?). I completed a certificate program in geographic information systems at a community college, and my GPA there was much better (3.84).

My low undergraduate GPA makes me anxious about my chances of being admitted. Is it worth working with application consultants to shore up my application package? ([examples](https://www.google.com/search?channel=tus5&client=firefox-b-1-d&q=graduate+school+application+consultants))

fwiw, my friends who went on to grad programs say my work experience is an advantage despite my low GPA. And my GPA over my final 60 credits, which is a criteria I see listed on some program pages, is 3.37.

Comment: Are you still a university student or a very recent graduate?

Comment: Although not a duplicate, this questions tackle a similar issue and may yield usefull answers as well: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-are-ph-d-applications-evaluated-in-the-us-particularly-for-weak-or-borderl

Comment: @Buffy - in May 2022 it will have been four years since I graduated. I had a few different jobs, but have been in my current engineering position for a year-and-a-half.

Comment: @Sursula-they- wow! thanks for that link. I did search for related questions prior to posting, but focused on looking for questions including "consultant" or "advisor." What you shared is a helpful reference to have.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a bachelors in engineering and want to get a master in engineering to increase your pay, I would suggest your best course of action is to gain work experience that will help you get into a high quality masters program.  Skip the paid consultant.

Answer (score 0):

These consultants help you navigate graduate school applications, which is otherwise a complicated process. In return for your money, you save time researching the application processes at different schools, get help choosing which schools to apply to, advice on choosing recommenders, help with managing any exams you must take (like the GRE), and a lot of other little stuff.

That's not to say you can't compensate for their work by putting in more time yourself, but you can't compensate for their experience.

If you can afford it, if you are working full-time and have less time to spend on applications, or if you are keen on getting a position *this year*, then I'd say it's worth it. If the cost is a real barrier, if you are currently unemployed or have lots of free time to do the research yourself, or if you have a good plan B if you are rejected everywhere this year (i.e. if you are OK failing this year and trying again next year), then you can consider saving the money and going it alone.